# Understanding hasOne() and belongsTo() functions in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, relationship

All I'm trying to do is understanding when exactly should I use `hasOne()` and when should I use `belongsTo()`. Both seem identical to me. For example, here is my model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Categories;
use App\User;


class tickets extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tickets";

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Categories::class, 'id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I can do the same by using `belongsTo()` function too. Just I should put them into `user` and `category` models instead. Anyway, when should I use either `hasOne()` or `belongsTo()` ?

Comment: What if you search before asking first? https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with 1 to many relationships, you will have a `hasMany()`and  a `belongsTo()` .

The rule of thumb I use, is if a table has a foreign key (tickets table has a `user_id` fk) then this model `belongsTo` users.
The same with Category.

So your above example, `Ticket` `belongsTo` `User` & `Category`.

Inversely, `User` `hasMany` `Ticket` and similarly `Category` `hasMany` `Ticket`

Answer (score 2):

> Anyway, when should I use either hasOne() or belongsTo() ?

Think of it like what would be `hasMany` if there is one to many relation probable in the future. For example: consider User and Phone models. Nature of relation would be User `hasOne` Phone, but if you would like to extend functionality for it so user could have multiple phone numbers registered User would still have `has*` relation while Phone would keep `belongsTo` relation. Just consider which one could be "parent" entity and that one should have `hasOne` relation in method. I would always consider User as parent entity and for me logically would be user has one ticket. 
Also, try to stick with Eloquent/Laravel/artisan naming convention and name that model `Ticket` and other one `Category` (Eloquent and Laravel will solve plural where needed i.e. table name).

Answer (score 2):

`hasOne` is a 1:1, or one-to-one relationship.

`hasMany` is a 1:n, or one-to-many relationship.

The `belongsTo` method in Eloquent is used **to define the inverse** of these relationships.

The definition of these will depend on your data model.

In your case:

You have a `Category` model, which `hasMany` `Ticket`s.

You also have a `User` model, which `hasMany` `Ticket`s.

Now from the Ticket perspective, you would want to define the inverses of these 2 `hasMany` relationships. You will do this by defining a `belongsTo`.

So the Ticket `belongsTo` a `User` and `belongsTo` a `Category`.

---

To answer your question:

From the `Ticket`s perspective, it **is** a 1:1 relation, because the foreign key in the Ticket model points to 1 User and the category foreign key points to 1 Category.

But since the relation you created is a 1:n (one-to-many) **and** you have also defined it on the User and Category models, you should define the relation in your Ticket model as the **inverse** of those relations, and the inverse of a hasMany (and hasOne) is `belongsTo`.

When defining your relations in Laravel, keep your database schema in mind and define your relations in the same way that they exist in your database schema.

Comment: You said in my case I have to use `belongsTo()`, but I'm using `hasOne()` and it works as expected .. Why should I use `belongsTo()` then?

Comment: @MartinAJ Read the last part of my comment where I answer that question. When defining relations in the code, you do so with your database schema in mind. A relation works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

These are same with a single difference. Both returns the single associated object with one difference. When we declare some relation as ***belongsTo*** it means there is a database table which has a foreign key of some other table. When we declare ***hasOne*** relation it means that this table's primary key has been referenced in another table. Think of it as a parent child table. When we would make the child table we reference each child to its parent, right? This is ***belongsTo***. And when we would make the parent table we know that each entry in parents table can have a single or many entries in the child table. That's ***hasOne*** or ***hasMany*** relation. You can ask further if you need any more clarification.